# Are verbose MouseListener implementations worth the overhead?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent, mouse-listeners

Consider the MouseListener below. My question is this: is having the extra features that this listener provides, **some of which you won't need**, worth the memory and processing overhead that comes with having these features? Or should "verbose" implementations like this be avoided?

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 * This is an overkill class that is useful for distinguishing between buttons and includes functions for hold and double-click events.
 *
 * @author Paranoid Android
 */
public class ParanoidMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

    public static final int LEFT = MouseEvent.BUTTON1;
    public static final int MIDDLE = MouseEvent.BUTTON2;
    public static final int RIGHT = MouseEvent.BUTTON3;

    private DoubleClickTimer leftDouble = new DoubleClickTimer();
    private DoubleClickTimer middleDouble = new DoubleClickTimer();
    private DoubleClickTimer rightDouble = new DoubleClickTimer();

    private MouseEvent event;
    private int pressedButton;
    private Component pressed;
    private boolean dragging;


    /**
     * This method allows methods to ignore the MouseEvent when not needed.
     *
     * @return the latest mouse event.
     */
    public MouseEvent getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    private HoldTimer leftHold = new HoldTimer() {

        @Override
        public void perform() {
            onLeftHold();
        }
    };
    private HoldTimer middleHold = new HoldTimer() {

        @Override
        public void perform() {
            onMiddleHold();
        }
    };
    private HoldTimer rightHold = new HoldTimer() {

        @Override
        public void perform() {
            onRightHold();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public final void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
        switch (event.getButton()) {
            case LEFT:
                if (leftDouble.isRunning()) {
                    leftDouble.stop();
                    onLeftDoubleClick();
                } else {
                    leftDouble.start();
                    onPureLeftClick();
                }
                break;
            case MIDDLE:
                if (middleDouble.isRunning()) {
                    middleDouble.stop();
                    onMiddleDoubleClick();
                } else {
                    middleDouble.start();
                    onPureMiddleClick();
                }
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                if (rightDouble.isRunning()) {
                    rightDouble.stop();
                    onRightDoubleClick();
                } else {
                    rightDouble.start();
                    onPureRightClick();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
        pressedButton = event.getButton();
        pressed = event.getComponent();
        switch (event.getButton()) {
            case LEFT:
                leftHold.start();
                onLeftPress();
                break;
            case MIDDLE:
                middleHold.start();
                onMiddlePress();
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                rightHold.start();
                onRightPress();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
        pressedButton = -1;
        Component src = event.getComponent();
        boolean contains = src.contains(event.getPoint());
        switch (event.getButton()) {
            case LEFT:
                leftHold.stop();
                onLeftRelease();
                if (!dragging && src == pressed && contains) onLeftClick();
                break;
            case MIDDLE:
                middleHold.stop();
                onMiddleRelease();
                if (!dragging && src == pressed && contains) onMiddleClick();
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                rightHold.stop();
                onRightRelease();
                if (!dragging && src == pressed && contains) onRightClick();
                break;
        }
        dragging = false;
    }

    @Override
    public final void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
        moved();
    }

    @Override
    public final void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
        dragging = true;
        switch (pressedButton) {
            case LEFT:
                onLeftDrag();
                break;
            case MIDDLE:
                onMiddleDrag();
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                onRightDrag();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
        entered();
    }

    @Override
    public final void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
        exited();
    }

    private int getDoubleClickInterval() {
        String property = "awt.multiClickInterval";
        return (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty(property);
    }

    private class DoubleClickTimer extends Timer {

        public DoubleClickTimer() {
            super(getDoubleClickInterval(), null);
            this.setRepeats(false);
        }
    }

    public int getHoldInitialDelay() {
        return 300;
    }

    public int getHoldQueueDelay() {
        return 60;
    }

    private class HoldTimer extends Timer {

        public HoldTimer() {
            super(getHoldQueueDelay(), null);

            this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    perform();
                }
            });
            this.setInitialDelay(getHoldInitialDelay());
        }

        public void perform() {
        }
    }

    public void moved() {
    }

    public void entered() {
    }

    public void exited() {
    }

    public void onLeftHold() {
    }

    public void onMiddleHold() {
    }

    public void onRightHold() {
    }

    public void onLeftClick() {
    }

    public void onMiddleClick() {
    }

    public void onRightClick() {
    }

    public void onPureLeftClick() {
    }

    public void onPureMiddleClick() {
    }

    public void onPureRightClick() {
    }

    public void onLeftDoubleClick() {
    }

    public void onMiddleDoubleClick() {
    }

    public void onRightDoubleClick() {
    }

    public void onLeftPress() {
    }

    public void onMiddlePress() {
    }

    public void onRightPress() {
    }

    public void onLeftRelease() {
    }

    public void onMiddleRelease() {
    }

    public void onRightRelease() {
    }

    public void onLeftDrag() {
    }

    public void onMiddleDrag() {
    }

    public void onRightDrag() {
    }
}
```

Comment: And what are your needs?

Comment: Who's your intended consumer? Is this a class only you will use, and if so, why implement features you don't want? If others will use it, what's the cost of these features and do you think they're likely to use them? Could you perhaps have consumers of the class communicate which features they intend to use and disable the rest, to make it more lightweight?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about these issues until you prove that are effectively a problem..

Comment: You should check out the practice of [Extreme Programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExtremeProgramming) called the [You Aren't Gonna Need it](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt) philosophy, or YAGNI.

Comment: My needs? I've personally encountered situations where I need to listen for double clicks and click holds on custom components and it's always an extra step to check for mouse buttons etc. This is just an idea to take care of everything abstractly.

Comment: Having encountered such a situation in the past is not necessarily a reason to write this class right now. Unless you intend to use it on your current project, or this is a just-for-fun sort of thing, you're better off waiting until you know that you need it, which helps reduce code bloat and improve maintainability.

Comment: Okay so what got me to come ask about it was this: I'm using this class currently in a large project that I'm working on and so far it's working like a charm. Some components use almost all of the methods but others only use 1 or 2, for example a `onLeftClick()`. In this case, should I use a standard `MouseAdapter` and check for the left button in the `mouseClicked()` or should I go ahead and add a `ParanoidMouseListener` anyway for conveniency and readability?

Comment: If the functionality can be covered by a `MouseAdapter`, then I would use that. It reduces dependency on your own code, which generally helps reduce bugs (though it seems unlikely that any exist here - but what if your class detects a double click and doesn't let it through, when you'd rather just have it pass as two left clicks?).

Comment: have look at SwingUtilities#isXxxMouse and together with AWTEventListener

Comment: @paranoid I upvoted your question to counter it - as far as I'm concerned it's a good question. I'll write up a summary of my comments.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Thanks again. I've decided it makes sense to let the mouse click go through regardless of the double click detection, rather than preventing the second click to funnel through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hovercraft Full Of Eels points out in the comments, this is a classic case of [You Aren't Gonna Need It](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt). Implementing functionality before you have a clear notion of who will use it and when is generally a no-no. In this situation, considering the use cases you outlined in the comments, you have several options:

- Use this class everywhere and accept the marginally higher overhead. Odds are you don't much care about the performance implications, which are likely to be very small. However, this does introduce a greater dependency on this class throughout the rest of your code, meaning if you introduce a regression at a later date, you're in risk of breaking a large number of related systems.
- Allow consumers of the class to indicate which features they will use (e.g., double clicking) and disable features that the consumer does not want. This introduces complexity into your class and makes it more likely to be buggy, as well as making testing more difficult (though hardly impossible). If consistency is badly needed between classes, this may be an option.
- Use this class when the added functionality is needed, and use an ordinary `MouseAdapter` elsewhere. This is probably your best option, especially if certain behavior cases are not well-defined in your custom class. This reduces dependency on your class and simplifies the class internally as well. The trade-off is less consistency in how mouse interaction is handled between consumer classes, and slightly more code in order to implement a `MouseAdapter` for consumers - generally a worthwhile trade-off.

Comment: Excellent. I'm going to go with #1 for now for the sake of consistency and if I find that the overhead noticibly affects performance I'll replace them with standard adapters. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you require these additional functionalities, there is no choice! If you do not require these functionalities, there is no point is using this extended listener class, again no choice!

Note that a few member fields and some additional code, it barely overhead compared to the rest of the Java VM and other code... So either choice: it does not really matter!

So again: pick what you require!